# Error with certain las functions in lidR including decimate_las

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to work with a las file from photogrammetry that is one tile from a retiled lascatalog. The las (v1.2) file is linked below. My issue occurs with other tiles too.

I can load the file using `readLAS` and can `plot(las)` but I get errors for `las_check(las)`, `decimate_las(las)`, and just trying to get the summary by typing `las` into the console.

This is the error:
`Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-") :  no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "bbox"`

Reproducible workflow:

1. Download data (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CbcXRrGypQm3D0_adPzdRajt9OXHmXX0/view?usp=sharing)
2. `las <- lidR::readLAS(file)`
3. `las_check(las)`

I'm using lidR version 4.0.0 in RStudio 1.3.1056.

Comment: Link to data isn't working.

Comment: @Pointdump: fixed

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. What is not working? `las_check`? `decimate_las` (This function does not exist)? or `print`? I tried `las_check` and `print` and it worked.

Comment: Not sure what else to offer. This is a las_check workflow that causes the error for me on the provided data. There are a number of other functions that lead to the same error including "print". Maybe this is a version issue for a lidR dependency?

Comment: I wonder if somehow your LAS data is storing the projection reference in a depreciated format. The decimate function is `lidR::decimate_points`. I have been using this package at this version for the past few days and have not seen any of the behavior you describe. You may want to make sure that all of your packages are up to date ie., run `update.packages` or select from the Packages menu in the R Console. I would also make sure that you are running R 4.1.0 and try running from the Console to rule out RStudio issues.

Comment: I'd try reinstalling lidR. That looks like a namespace clash from badly installed packages. I've already seen similar kind of issues in the past.

Comment: I've now tried: 1) reinstalling lidR; 2) updating all packages not requiring compilation; 3) updating RStudio; 4) running the code in R rather than RStudio; 5) running a completely different las file from distinct origin. No luck! Same error.

Comment: Downgraded to lidR 3.2.3 and now things work again. This process also involved "updating" a bunch of other packages (requiring compilation). So, now I'll try to upgrade lidR again...

Comment: Yes. Re-upgrading to lidR 4.0 and things still work (e.g., las_check, print()). I wonder why a user is not forced/asked to update all required packages when doing a lidR update? I was only asked to make the relevant updates when doing a downgrade. Anyhow, thanks all! Hopefully, this is the end of it.

Comment: related: with 3.1.2 I'm getting "Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  assignment of an object of class “logical” is not valid for @‘proj4string’ in an object of class “LAS”; is(value, "CRS") is not TRUE" when running the first two example lines in `?readLAS`. I'm guessing compatibility problems with `sf[1.0.1]` or `sp[1.4.5]` packages? all working with lidR 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `lidR` versions 3.x are having some issues with compatibility with other packages. Here's a reproducible (for me anyway) example:

```
> library(lidR)
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sp
lidR 3.1.4 using 2 threads. Help on <gis.stackexchange.com>. Bug report on <github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR>.
Warning messages:
1: multiple methods tables found for ‘direction’ 
2: multiple methods tables found for ‘gridDistance’ 
3: multiple methods tables found for ‘area’
```

Some warnings we can probably ignore. Okay let's run the first example in the help for `readLAS`:

```
>  LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
>      las = readLAS(LASfile)
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  assignment of an object of class “logical” is not valid for @‘proj4string’ in an object of class “LAS”; is(value, "CRS") is not TRUE
```

With these versions of `sp` and `sf`:

```
> packageVersion("sp")
[1] ‘1.4.5’
> packageVersion("sf")
[1] ‘1.0.1’
```

That's not looking good... But reinstalling `lidR` up to version 4.0.0 and its now fully working.

Comment: `multiple methods tables` are typical errors coming from nowhere and related somehow to an installation issue. I encountered that on windows and the errors were resolved by reinstalling a clean R version. The proj4string issue is also a problem of corrupted binaries reported here https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/issues/485 and unsolvable on my side. Both lidR 3.2.0 and 4.0.0 are working good but many troubles on which I have no control happen with bad/weird windows binaries. Sometime it is only tempory and it is fixed when the CRAN generates a new binary. It is not reproducible by everybody.

Comment: How about I accept this answer if some of JRR's thoughts from the comment are incorporated to provide more general context?

Comment: I'm not sure. I might just delete this. I'm not even using binaries, building all packages from source. I sort of want to downgrade and see if I can re-break things and really track down the error, but I sort of don't want to, because upgrading to 4.0.0 seems like the first thing you should do anyway. Meh...